# Prevent rpm from being uninstalled

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

I have built an RPM Package that I use for several clients to do some stuff and install things, but I want to know if there is any way that I could prevent users or apps from uninstalling this RPM file?!

Comment: I do not think you can.

Comment: Preventing uninstallation of the package doesn't prevent removal of the files.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I do not think you can prevent uninstallation of a package, uninstallation is performed by the package manager (RPM/YUM) itself.

Comment: @leeduhem: What I'm saying is that even if you *could*, it wouldn't help.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Agreed, it would not.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Couldn't you make it so that as part of installation you chattr +i the files so that yum couldn't remove it even if it wanted to?

Comment: @JasonZhu: There is nothing stopping them from resetting it.

Comment: thanks to all of you I finally had a thought that I could run a script to save some of my files on the uninstallation process but as you said there's no stopping people to delete files if they have access.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at using `%config` and/or `%ghost` instead.